# using re to find nested results in strings

Tags: python, regex

hi all I have the string below:

```
test = '<tr> <stuff1> <tr><stuff2> </tr> </tr>'
```

and I would like python to return the following:

```
result=['<tr><stuff1><tr><stuff2></tr></tr>','<tr><stuff2></tr>']
```

I've tried `re.finall('<tr>.+</tr>',test)` but that just returns the entire string ...

Thanks

Comment: Don't parse [html/xml](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) with regexes... Regexes aren't the right tool for it.

Comment: @user5061: now imagine you are parsing a table with `<tr class="foo">`. The rules of html/xhtml are extremely complicated...

Comment: Using `.+?` instead of `.+` would match "as few as possible", probably solving your problem. _Note: Regular expressions **should not** be used for your problem._

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a html parser to parse html:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """<tr> <stuff1> <tr><stuff2> </tr> </tr>"""
soup =BeautifulSoup(html)

print(soup.find_all("tr"))
```